# Linker command failed _main not found

Tags: c, macos, clang

I'm a college student beginner in C language. I was trying to run a program in which a matrix initializes with all values = 0, then the user enters values and finally the program searches a user input number inside a matrix, telling the row and column of said value.

But this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

won't stop coming up (I use visual studio code for mac) and I cannot get rid of it.

I've been searching all over internet but I can't find a solution and my teacher said "never heard of this error." I would appreciate your help :)

The function in which I need help is `CercadorNumero`.

I have two libraries, main library and functions library.

main:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILA 3
#define COLUMNA 3

void printMatriu (int entraMatriu[FILA][COLUMNA]);
int sumaFila (int matriu[][COLUMNA], int numFila);
int CercadorNumero (int buscaMatriu[FILA][COLUMNA], int valor, int *p, int *f); //p i f indicaran les cordenades

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    int matriu [FILA][COLUMNA];

    for (int i=0; i<FILA; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<COLUMNA; j++)
        {
            matriu[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<FILA; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<COLUMNA; j++)
        {

            do{

                printf("Entrant el valor de la columna %d, fila %d: ", i+1, j+1);
                scanf("%2d", &matriu[i][j]);
            }while(matriu[i][j]<0 || matriu[i][j]>15);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    printMatriu(matriu);


    int suma, numFila;

    for(int i = 0; i < FILA; i++)
    {
        suma = sumaFila(matriu, i);
        printf("La suma de la fila %d es: %d\n", i+1, suma);
    }

    int resultat, numCercar, columnaTrobada, filaTrobada;
    
    do{

        printf("Diga'm el numero que vols buscar: \n");
        scanf("%d", &numCercar);
        resultat = CercadorNumero (matriu, numCercar, &columnaTrobada, &filaTrobada); 
        
        if (resultat == 1)
        {
            printf("%d Trobat a les coordenades: %d %d", numCercar, columnaTrobada, filaTrobada);
        } else
        {
            printf("valor no trobat");
        }
        
    } while(numCercar<0 || numCercar>100);

    return 0;

}
```

functions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILA 3
#define COLUMNA 3

void printMatriu (int entraMatriu[FILA][COLUMNA]){

for (int i=0; i<FILA; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j<COLUMNA; j++){ 
            printf("%2d ", entraMatriu[i][j]); 

        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }

}

int sumaFila (int matriu[][COLUMNA], int numFila)
{

    int suma=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNA; j++)
    {
        suma = suma + matriu[numFila][j];
    }

    return suma;
}

int CercadorNumero (int buscaMatriu[FILA][COLUMNA], int valor, int *p, int *f)
{
    int valorResultat = 0;
    *p = 0;
    *f = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < FILA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNA;)
        {
            if (buscaMatriu[i][j] == valor)
            {
                valorResultat = 1;
                *p = i; //posició de memoria p guarda el valor de i en el moment que es igual al valor (fila)
                *f = j; //posició de memoria f guarda el valor de j en el moment que es igual al valor (columna)
                return valorResultat;
            } else j++;
        }
    }
    return valorResultat;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the *entire unedited* error message.

Comment: ... but my wild guess is that you are using "code runner" or a similar vscode extension designed to run a *single* C file, so your file with functions is never looked at. The easiest workaround at this point is to simply put everything in one file, but it is not scalable. If you want to fix it for real, look up questions about running more than one C file in VS Code.

Comment: Oh and if your teacher never heard of this error, you may want to find a better teacher :(

Comment: You should not only read the summary of linker output. Start at the top of the messages and look for errors. The final "something went wrong" is not useful at all.

Comment: just edited, but i think you for your help! I think were right, sorry its my first time using stack overflow im still a begginar

Comment: @vmichavila2 Everything is okay, I'm a beginner here too :)

Comment: @zhengliw and vmichavila2: There are so many helpful pages at [help], and you might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.